# setRawHeader doesn't follow elements in the web view

Tags: c++, qt, webkit

I want to test the rendering of a configured vhost before the hostname is set.

Exemple : view the webpage "otherNameOfMySite" located at mysite.com if the dns entry "otherNameOfMySite" doesn't exist (but the apache vhost is set).

My code :

```
webvhost = new QWebView();
QNetworkRequest * request = new QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://mysite.com"));
request->setRawHeader("Host","otherNameOfMySite");
webvhost->load(*request);
```

The header is set only for the main page, if there is another element in the html page like an image, the download of this image will not use the header I configured. In my case I can't view the render of possible vhost.

How can I tell webview to use this header with all elements of the web page ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't the host send out the right html in the first place? There will be new requests for every element the web view downloads.

Comment: I think you should probably precise why you want to do that in the first place profy.

Comment: Hum maybe the better way is to set a proxy, I will try ...

Comment: proxy doesn't allow to modify header of the http request :(

Answer (score 0):

1. You should reimplement `QNetworkAccessManager` class, particularly, `createRequest` function where you can manually set any header for all requests.
2. Create instance of this reimplemented class and set it in `webvhost->page()->setNetworkAccessManager(your_reimplemented_class)`.
   So, you'll get what you want.